# Relative efficiency of n tasks in 1 loop vs. 1 task each in n loops?

Tags: time-complexity, loops

Say I have 3 simple tasks, to find the min, the max, and the average of an array of numbers.

A modular approach would be to write one function for each, thus iterating over the array thrice. However, that seems wasteful when all the information can be collected in a single iteration.

I understand that both approaches take `3n` time but am wondering if one approach is better than the other in the general case and why.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting the information in a single iteration would be way better, but you'll only notice the difference if your array contains a large number of numbers. On a small scale, it just won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to compute all of them. You can find in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13546518/3768871) the implementation of `min` and `max` with each other using `3n/2 - 2` comparison instead of `2n`. Also, summing the values in the meanwhile of iterating over the whole of the data. It's the minimum number of iteration and comparison over data.

Comment: That is a good approach for the example of min, max, and average.  What about the general case?

Comment: @wsaleem You can't talk about it in general case

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should do whatever code is more readable. If you need to find min, max, and sum or average, then having a single function that does exactly what it needs to do is the simplest and most readable approach. It's all in one place. If I need to check what the function does, I don't have to hunt around in different places. So usually, you should have one function.

If performance is more important than readability, then you should also have one function. You will read n array elements instead of 3n. You can determine min and max simultaneously with 1.5n comparison instead of 2n. On multi-issue CPUs where performance is limited by latency, you have 1x latency instead of 3x latency, so your code could be up to 3 times faster.

Comment: Aren't atomic functions more readable and reusable?